# «Мозговой штурм» употребляется на письме в кавычках или без?

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, выбор-слов

«Мозговой штурм» употребляется на письме в кавычках или без?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Грамота.ру дает такой ответ:

> К настоящему времени этот оборот получил широкое распространение,
>   поэтому писать его следует без кавычек.

См. [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%88%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BC)